# Android UI Designing - is using android studio UI editor enough?

Tags: android

I've been learning Android for the past few days and I'm getting increasingly confused about one particular topic - the design of the UI.

I'm currently using Constraint Layout, as selected by default in Android Studio.
I wonder how can I make the UI screen-size independent? Some people say guidelines (if so - where to insert them? What to do with them? What is their purpose? How is it different than just placing a button there?), some people say that good constraints are enough, some people say that I should use Relative Layout and make separate UIs for different screen sizes. I also have problems with understanding the whole concept of dp, it's kinda hard to wrap my head around it. What's the difference between using percentage values and using dp? Is dp screen-dependent?

Not to mention that I find it hard to understand the whole concept of resolution, etc. 
What should I start with?

Comment: *Is dp screen-dependent?* dp is short for dip which actually means density **independent** pixel

Answer (score 0):

Start with a proper tutorial on android.
I would suggest to go through the Udacity basic nanodegree program. https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-nanodegree-by-google--nd803 Also my friend Google is your best teacher only you have to have the passion for it